# Use heightmaps or direct vertex manipulation for runtime terrain editing in UE4?

Tags: terrain, unreal-4, vertex, procedural, world-editor

I am creating a terrain editor and creator for in our game, in which we should be able to create hills and dales, create different shapes(forms) in the terrain etc. I came up with 2 approaches on achieving what we want,

**1.** modify 2d heightmaps by darkening / lightening colours; update terrain vertices based thereon.

**2.**  Create a plane and modify the vertices of the plane to shape what we want.

So my question is, which way would be faster/better for a ingame terrain editor? And why would you recommend that?

Or, if you know of a better way, I would love to hear.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a situation where you could quickly prototype both options and profile them to see whether one is faster, or discover in the process of implementation whether one is neater/more scalable & maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Provides an intermediate data structure.

(2) Is exactly the same as (1) but it provides no such structure.

Do you need an intermediate tonal heightmap? If you don't, then don't use one. Individual vertex *typically* offers finer control over terrain, which from an aesthetic perspective is preferable. You can also have the heightmap represent the heights of *vertices* and not *tiles*, which you may mean in (1).

For example, a game where the player must be able to stand on a flat tile at every point (think Minecraft) is better off using a heightmap, since otherwise you will have non-flat tiles if you edit vertices individually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think i will just start developing the second option, and if i don't like it, I will just convert it over.
with option 1. i meant to have each vertex in the picture, but i think i might be better off just saving the z values in an array(which is probably faster then reading a texture anyway), thanks